# rospy equivalent to ros::NodeHandle nh("namespace")

Tags: ros, rospy, namespace, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm very new to ROS and am [slightly] more versed in `python` than `C++`, so that's the route I'm currently pursuing in my learning. One option that is shown in the `C++` tutorials is how one would [set a custom namespace](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles#Namespaces) or parent namespace :

> You can also specify a parent NodeHandle and a namespace to append:

```
### adding the initialization call from above
ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node_name");

ros::NodeHandle nh1("ns1");
ros::NodeHandle nh2(nh1, "ns2");
```

In the `python` [information](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown), I've only ever seen this used, which I take as equivalent to `ros::init()`:

```
rospy.init_node('my_node_name')
```

How would one put node `my_node_name` into a custom or parent namespace using `rospy`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261862/rospy-equivalent-to-ros::nodehandle-nh(%22namespace%22)/) by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospy` doesn't have a direct analog to the `ros::NodeHandle` in C++. If you do need to resolve names relative to the node name (or another name) in Python, you can use `rospy.resolve_name(name, caller_id=None)`, but instead of a dedicated object this just return a string.

There's some documentation about this on the [rospy Names and Node Information](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Names%20and%20Node%20Information) wiki.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2